# Can I define a minimum turn radius with the dwa_planner?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with a robot that can turn in a way similar to a car and thus cannot turn in place and has a minimum turn radius. Is the dwa_planner capable of being configured for that kind of robot? I've read the documentation, and it seems that even when setting holonomic = false it still assumes that linear velocity and rotational velocity are independent variables.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227766/can-i-define-a-minimum-turn-radius-with-the-dwa_planner?/) by [zacwitte](https://answers.ros.org/users/26086/zacwitte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2016-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. Search for a different local planner.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0